# exporting war file in jdeveloper 10g

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, project, deployment, jdeveloper

how can i export .war file in jdeveloper 10g ?

Answer (score 1):

you can build for web application from jdevloper and then there is a option to build the jar/war file at a particular location in properties option for that project.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a war file for an UI application. Click on the application, select project properties and navigate to the deployments tab. Select the type of deployment as WAR and add the dependencies. Once this done, you can click on the deploy option to deploy this. This would get deployed in the Deploy folder of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the "Application Navigator " where you can see the Model and view of your project . Then click on the "New" then select "Deployment profiles", there u go , now u can select the format u need jar , war , ear , mar etc